# Breaking change between Selenium 3.x/4.x NuGet causes problems with testing Electron app

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron

**Some context:**

- C# / .NET Framework 4.8
- Selenium.WebDriver NuGet / Chromedriver.exe extracted in some directory

**I have a short sample code like this:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace Draft
{
    public class SeleniumTest
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUpBrowser()
        {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.BinaryLocation = @"FullPathToMyElectronApp.exe";

            ChromeDriverService chromeService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\\chromedriver", @"chromedriver.exe");
            chromeService.Port = 9999;
            chromeService.Start();
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeService, options);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CloseBrowser()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:**

This code works like a charm with Selenium.WebDriver **2.x/3.x**.
It opens an electron app window, waits a moment and closes it.

But when I update Selenium.WebDriver NuGet to version **4.x** the test code just executes but no window shows up...
It also breaks my tests with timeout exception.

I guess that there was some breaking change but I haven't figured out what causes this behavior :/

**Any idea?...**

**Edit:**
Hmm... I am a bit desperate so I've checked out prereleases and this code works with Selenium.WebDriver `v4.0.0a1`! It looks like the **breaking change is in `v4.0.0a2`**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exception message and stack trace.

Comment: @GregBurghardt
There is no exception thrown in this example code. **Just nothing happens.**

All of exceptions in my real code are caused because of Electron app is not being loaded so using any `WebDriverWait` causes `WebDriverTimeoutException` as it should be.

Comment: Ok. I was curious, because you said *"It also breaks my tests with timeout exception"*. Very curious that there simply is no error or reaction.

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: It's a `2.36` version of chromedriver.exe (yes, I know - a bit ancient).
I have no idea how to check Chrome version in app...

Comment: Open Chrome, Help --> About. The first thing I would do is [update ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection).

Comment: Long story short, the major version of Chrome needs to be the same as the major version of ChromeDriver. With ChromeDriver 2.x, you are *years* out of date. Unless you haven't updated Chrome in years as well. Usually weird problems like this indicate you need to install the proper version of ChromeDriver for your Google Chrome installation.

Comment: It's about **compiled Electron app** - not a Chrome. I don't have an influence to update this app.

Comment: I was told that it's Electron v20 (surprise...) so I updated chromedriver to v104 but nothing changed